# How to get two values from a DropdownButtonFormField

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dropdown

I need help getting two values from a DropdownButtonFormField. The dropdown form items is a list created from documents in Firestore. This is my Dropdown:

```
  return DropdownButtonFormField(
      isExpanded: true,
      decoration: textInputDecoration,
      value: _currentUser,

      hint: Text(
        'Select User',
      ),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() => _currentUser = val);
        setState(() => UserDropdownList.some = val);
      },
      items: user.map((user){
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: user.userId,
          child: Text(user.name)
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

From my dropdown, I get the userId as the value while on the dropdown, the name is displayed as text. I would however like a second value that can take the name of the selected user alongside the userId. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dropdownmenuitem` only has one property for the `value`, you can do the following:

```
items: user.map((user){
  return DropdownMenuItem(
    value: ${user.userId}_${user.name},
    child: Text(user.name)
     );
  }).toList(),
```

This will give you the value with both the id and the name of the user.

Comment: Thanks. This works and it takes both values. now my challenge is getting the individual values (userId and name) from the resulting string. Like if I was to set state. 
currently: 
setState(() => _currentUser = val);
gets the String. If I could do like 
setState(() => _currentUser = val.name);

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: just use split on the variable https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html

Answer (score 1):

Making references to the split method as pointed out by Peter

one can try this

```
items: user.map((user){
 return DropdownMenuItem(
value: user["your_data"].toString() + " " + user["another_data"].toString(), 
// output = your_data  another_data
child: Text(user.name)
 );
  }).toList(),
```

to get the two values separately

```
print(_currentUser.split(" ")[0]); // will print your data

print(_currentUser.split(" ")[1]); // will print another data
```